# how to prevent log output from PostgreSQL stored procedure?

Tags: configuration, logging, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am running a number of PostgreSQL scripts that used to produce excessive log output. I managed to reduce most of the output to an acceptable amount by passing `--quiet` as parameter to the psql command line client and adding `SET client_min_messages='warning';` to the beginning of my SQL scripts.

This works fine for most basic statements like SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, etc.) However, when I call a stored function in a script using e.g. `SELECT my_func(my_args);`, there is still log output similar to

`my_func`

(omitted a long with many '-' here because SF thinks that's a headline)

`(1 row)`

The output is useless; it only makes me having to scroll back up a long way after the script has run and also makes it much harder than necessary to spot any relevant error output.

How can I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to be running the script from psql, you could do

```
copy ( select my_func(my_args) ) to stdout;
```

or even

```
\copy ( select my_func(my_args) ) to /dev/null
```

You could specify "-A -t" on the psql command line to globally quieten the output of all query statements to a single line.

Comment: fantastic! thanks for the tip! :-)

If -q is added to the -A -t parameters, the COPY log output is also suppressed.
Now all I see is warnings and errors, just what I wanted.

Comment: PS: care to remove the \ in front of \copy so later readers don't get confused ?

Comment: The second \ is intentional... you can't do `COPY ... TO file` unless you're a superuser, whereas a client-side \copy will work for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Either

```
\o /dev/null
SELECT my_func(my_args);
```

or

```
SELECT my_func(my_args) \g /dev/null
```

Comment: That's much more elegant that copy/\copy hackage.